# File explorer show nothing

Tags: android, root

I'm using Eclipse Indigo,

I'm root on my device.

When I'm running application and looking at File explorer in eclipse I see nothing. (can't see folders at all)

The windows is empty.

What can I do?

Comment: I am facing the same situation. Is there a way to get over it ? I have also rooted my phone.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the device to see something either in logcat or in file explorer

```
Window->show view -> other -> Android -> device ->
```

you will get device icon in you eclipse. open that device to check what are the connected devices (emulators also) if you get the device for which you want to see either logcat or file explorer. in the list then select it if you dont find any list there then restart the device (same for emulators also)

If this doesnt work then restart your eclipse and do these steps again.

Comment: 10x, but I can see my device there. And the logcat works just fine. The only problem is that the file explorer is empty

Comment: How did you overcome the problem? I'm stuck in you're same position, and the Internet looks like is not going to help me out...

Answer (score -4):

I know this is old thread but just for sharing knowledge.

Show your devices by going to:

> Window->show view -> other -> Android -> device ->

If you still can't see any folders in file manager, go and lunch your emulator. Once it completely loads you should see the device appears in the devices tab.

Comment: is this not just a copy of the answer given 2 years ago?

Comment: @Doomsknight No, I'm providing a solution in case you still can't see anything even after clicking on the device.

Comment: he also states to restart/start device or emulator too.